# Can I use PHP with a webpack front-end?

Tags: php, webpack

I have a webpack project using html and js files. The js files take some data, visualize the data using D3, and then append the visualizations in an HTML file. Also, all the JS files get bundled together via Webpack.

For the next feature of my project, I want to collect user input, and write that input to a database. Every time a user loads my project, the database will be visualized.

So for example, let's say I have this form

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal information:</legend>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

And I have the PHP send this data to the database.

Is it possible for another PHP script to get the database data and then push that data to one of my .js files? I just don't understand the workflow, or how webpack works with backend in general.

I think PHP is unique because it is embedded in HTML. Is it possible to run it purely in a server context and return some data in an API endpoint that I can access with .js? Or can I do what I need just by embedding it in HTML?

Comment: "I think PHP is unique because it is embedded in HTML" — Hardly unique. [1](http://www.template-toolkit.org/). [2](https://ejs.co/). [3](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagy.html). [4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/#the-django-template-language). [5](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2)